# Inconsistency in Vertex Factor in Scalar QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics

I'm trying to find the vertex factor for the scalar-scalar-gluon-gluon interaction. The diagram is

[image: vertex]

This corresponds to the term $g^2 \phi^{\dagger}A_{\mu}^a\left(T^aT^b\right)_{ij}A_{\mu}^b\phi_j$ in the Lagrangian density. Naively, I expect the factor to be 
$$
-ig^2\left(T^aT^b\right)_{ij}g^{\mu\nu},
$$
which is what appears in Schwartz's book. However, other sources have
$$
-ig^2\left(T^aT^b + T^bT^a\right)_{ij}g^{\mu\nu}.
$$

Which is correct? This makes a difference in calculation I'm doing (finding the beta function in scalar Yang-Mills theory), in which I have the following corrections to the three-point vertex:

[image: diagram]

If I use Schwartz's convention, the color factor is $T^bT^aT^b$, which can be rewritten as $\left(C(R) -\frac{1}{2}T(A)\right)T^a$. If I use the other convention, I have an extra factor of $C(R)T^a$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A^a_\mu A^b_\nu g^{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric in $a$ and $b$, only symmetric part of $T_aT_b$, i.e. $\frac{1}{2}(T_aT_b + T_bT_a)$ should contribute to the vertex. Also, since the term is quadratic in gauge potential, you get a combinatoric factor of 2.

You can also compute functional derivative of the action, $\frac{\partial S}{\partial \phi^\dagger_i \partial\phi_j \partial A^a_\mu \partial A^b_\nu}$, to obtain the correct expression for the vertex.

Comment: Ok, so only the symmetric part matters. But since I'm not actually contracting the $T^a$ matrices with any gluons when I compute the vertex correction, why do I still get an extra factor of $C(R)T^a$? Will this factor drop out in an actual diagram?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand where the combinatoric factor comes from. I thought we could always just extract the vertex terms from the Lagrangian density.